# Kicad - Module refernces are being rendered, but don't show up on gerber plots

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, gerber, silkscreen

I am working on an open source design. I can view all the layers in PCBNew. The module references show up on the screen. They are visible even when I deselect Front Silk Screen (F.SilkS) in the layers menu. Under the "Render" tab, I have to select all three: "Text Front", "Modules Front" and "References" to see these values.

However, when I plot the Silk Screen, the values do not show up in the Gerber files. I have selected "Plot module values on silkscreen", "Plot module references on silkscreen" and "Plot other module texts on silkscreen". Still, they don't show up on the SilkScreen Gerber Files. I am viewing the gerber files with GerbV.

How can I make the module references appear on the Silk Screen gerber output?

Update: The Kicad project is available here: https://github.com/bkkcoins/klondike/tree/master/kicad

Comment: I tried plotting your nano.brd and got very strange results. Might be a shot in the dark, but have you tried converting to the new board format (.kicad_pcb)?

Comment: I am actually working on K16.

Comment: Have you tried a the most recent -stable version of Kicad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up editing the .brd file manually. All the modules were on layer 26 and I moved them to layer 21. For lines T0 and T1 for every module, the 9th value was 26. I changed them to 21.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are visible in pcbnew (not hidden), they should show up in the gerbers.

Make sure you select front and back silk when plotting the gerbers. The output should be named $PROJECT.gto or .gbo, if i'm not mistaken. (gerber, top|bottom outline).

Comment: If I edit the parameters of the module, and change the side from "Top" to "Bottom", the reference shows up on the Bottom SilkScreen Gerber File. Also, when I point the cursor at "Text Front" under the render tab, the tooltip says: "Show footprint text on boards back". Does this tell anything?